# Line bundles on complex tori

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

There is a line bundle-divisor correspondence. Namely, given a divisor $D$ which is a formal sum of codimension $1$ subvarieties, we can write $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ to be the line bundle whose sections have prescribed zeroes and poles.

Line bundles on complex tori $V/\Lambda$ can also be described by a hermitian form $H$ on $V$ with a corresponding semicharacter on $H$ by Appel-Humbert Theorem. The content of Appel-Humbert theorem is that every line bundle can be described up to isomorphism by such line bundles $L(H,\chi)$.

Suppose we have a complex abelian variety (i.e. a complex tori with an ample line bundle or a positive definite Riemann form) and we look at $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ for a divisor $D$.

Is there a way to describe what $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ is in the language of Appel-Humbert? For example, I would like to know how we can describe $H=c_1(\mathcal{O}_X(D))$. Maybe this is too ambitious.

I would also like to know if $\deg D$ (i.e. if $D=\sum n_i D_i$, $\deg D=\sum n_i$) is equal to the degree of the isogeny, $\lambda_{\mathcal{O}_X(D)}, a\mapsto t_a^*L\otimes L^{-1}$ where $L=\mathcal{O}_X(D)$. Of course knowing what $c_1(\mathcal{O}_X(D))$ would help since if we know $\lambda_L$ is of type $(d_1,...,d_g)$ its degree is simply $\prod_{i=1}^g d_i$.

Comment: I'm not aware of any general principle, but I did calculate an example some weeks ago, see [this question + answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4722773/how-to-determine-the-type-of-a-divisor-d-on-a-product-of-elliptic-curves).

Comment: You should also know that on a general complex torus, there are no non trivial subvarieties.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Surely, you mean "no non trivial abelian subvarieties"? Given that abelian varieties are projective, I can always intersect with a hyperplane to get subvarieties by Bertini.

Comment: @daruma Not all complex tori are projective. By definition, abelian varieties are projective complex tori, but your question does not mention the projectivity assumption.

Comment: @red_trumpet Yes you are right. I should have said complex tori with an ample line bundle.